# Hidden arguments from Javascript to Django view

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views

I am currently working on integrating `Facebook Login` into my website.

In javascript, I was able to fetch the user's information the moment (s)he logs to my website; via Facebook.

So, part of my javascript code is the following:

```
...
u_email = response.email;      //gets user's email
u_fname = response.first_name; //gets user's first name
```

...and so on!

Now I would like to do one of the two following scenarios: 1) If this is the first time the user logs in into my website; I would like to save all this information (email, first name, ...) to my users' database; 2) If this is not the first time the user logs in, I would like to redirect the user to another page, and display some information about him/her that I will need to get from the database (according to his/her email)!

In either case, I will have to access the database through the user's information. So, what I would like to do, is to redirect the user to a Django view while passing the user's information. For example, I can have the following in my javascript file:

```
document.location.href = '../' + u_email +'/' + u_fname + '/login';
```

...and in my `urls.py`, I can have the following:

```
url(r'^(?P<u_email>\w+)/(?P<u_fname>\w+)/login/$', views.login, name='login')
```

Lastly, in my `view` file, I can have the following:

```
def login(request, u_email, u_fname):
    template = loader.get_template('counters/login.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'u_email': u_email,
        'u_fname': u_fname,
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Now; clearly, I have a problem, that is, the user's (supposedly secretive) information will be shown in the url! Is there a way to avoid it by hiding the arguments passed from the javascript to the Django view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not have url patterns based on critical information a potential attacker should not be able to see. This type of information should be passed to the server side using a POST request method in an encrypted ssl or tls request.

But for your usecase a better approach to achieve that is to :

1. use the FB javascript api to login on client side and get a FB token
2. send a POST https request to your backend and have your backend code requesting the user information using the FB Graph Api. (the ssl and tls request is necessary to pass the access_token information in POST mode, this is here the sensitive data)

```
#the view code
#import your user model here
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

@POST_required
def login(request, facebookId):
    if token is not None:
        #query graph api
        r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/{facebook_id}?fields=email,name&access_token={token}'.format({'facebook_id':facebook_id, 'token':token}))
        facebook_email = r.json()['email']
        facebook_name = r.json()['name']

        #check if first login
        try:
            user = Users.object.get(email=facebook_email, name=facebook_name)
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            user = Users.objects.create(email=facebook_email, name=facebook_name)
        render_to_response('counter/login.html', dictionnary={'user':user}, context=RenderContext(request))
```

```
    #url conf code
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    import views

    url_patterns = url('', 
        patterns(r'^(?Pw+)/login/$', views.login)
```

Comment: Very nice :) - Thanks! Do you know if it's possible (and if it's a good idea) to log in from Django (view) immediately (similar to http requests) and not use JavaScript at all! I'm just curious!

Comment: By the way; don't you need 'token' added to the parameters list in 'def login(request, facebookId, [here])'?

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot about that : as it is a POST parameter just retrieve it using the request.POST dictionnary (request.POST['token'])

Answer (score 0):

According you have an `Model` to save the `User` information and his `email` is unique.

```
def login(request, u_email, u_fname):
    try:
        # Try to get the User in your DB
        user = YourUserModel.objects.get(email=u_email)
        # Do your redirects.
    except YourUserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Do your other stuffs, like add this new user in your DB

    template = loader.get_template('counters/login.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'u_email': u_email,
        'u_fname': u_fname,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```